# docker-compose tty performance issues

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and currently working on a project with docker-compose. I use a docker-compose.yml file with the build command referencing to the Dockerfile of my service.

**docker-compose.yml (part of):**

```
services:
  server:
    build: server
    expose:
      - 8080
    volumes:
    - ./server/crypto:/server/crypto
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    [tty: true]
```

**Dockerfile (server):**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libssl-dev \
    libpq-dev
WORKDIR /server
COPY server.c .
RUN gcc -o server server.c \
    -L/usr/lib \
    -I/usr/include/postgresql \
    -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -lpq
ENTRYPOINT ["./server"]
```

Server.c is a simple server program continuously listening and connecting to clients over sockets, communicates over TLS and has a connection to a postgres db.

Actually, everything is working just fine, but I'm experiencing strange performance issues. Starting the program with the command *docker-compose up -d* and without the *tty: true* in docker-compose, I get really high CPU loads on my mac (100-120%). However, running it with *tty: true*, the loads decrease to (10-20%).
My research showed that tty opens a pseudo-terminal but I'm clueless how it is related to my performance problems.

Comment on the server Dockerfile: I know that you should use the correct docker image instead of ubuntu and installing all dependencies. Since the image has a size of 1.3GB using the gcc image from docker-hub and only 300MB using ubuntu and installing the packages, I don't see the advantages of using the gcc image. Maybe anyone has a recommendation on that too.

**Addition (loop reading from stdin):**

```
do {
    fgets(read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer), stdin);
} while (strcmp(read_buffer, "SHUTDOWN\n") != 0);
```

Comment: How does this Server.C is made? You can get a 100% CPU usage when you use a while (true) expression. You can fix this by just adding a small ms delay after every iteration of the while.

Comment: Ok, I found something using your hint. I am reading from stdin using fgets() [see addition above], but without tty: true and stdin_open: true, there is no stdin. Therefore the loop is executed continuously instead of halting and reading.

Thank you!